# sprintf rounding

Tags: php

Why does the following produce different results?

```
echo 2.55 * 100;
echo sprintf(' %d', 2.55 * 100);
```

output:

```
255 254
```

Comment: [Starting point](http://floating-point-gui.de/)

Comment: @MarkBaker That is no starting point for his problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `2.55 * 100` in base 2 fixed size representation is not an integer and `%d` does not round:

```
var_dump(sprintf('%d', 1.99));
```

```
string(1) "1"
```

```
ini_set('precision', 20);
var_dump(2.55 * 100);
```

```
float(254.99999999999997158)
```

Unlike `printf()`, `echo $numeric_variable` does not have a dedicated mechanism to convert from string to number. It merely casts to string using the [default rules](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.casting), so it's identical to `(string)$numeric_variable` or `strval($numeric_variable)`. In this case:

- Since variable type is `float` it attempts to represent a float (that implies converting from binary IEEE 754 to decimal).
- It reads the [precision](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.precision) directive to fine-tune the representation:

  > The number of significant digits displayed in floating point numbers. `-1` means that an enhanced algorithm for rounding such numbers will be used.

To reduce the error in IEEE 754 to decimal conversion, string casting rounds as necessary. In my computer default `precision` is `14`, which is pretty close to the number of nines.

Comment: @Xatenev Please note there're many 9's. You are relying on default precision (`ini_get('precision')`);

Comment: Just realized my mistake. +1